# Spec2/JUnit/Eclipse shows Unrooted Tests with more than two examples

Tags: eclipse, scala, junit, specs2

This is very perplexing. If I remove the 3rd example in the code below, JUnit runner in Eclipse shows the test results in the usual hierarchy. As soon as the third example is added, all 3 tests drop out into Unrooted Tests category.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.AllExpectations

@RunWith(classOf[org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner])
class ThreeTests extends Specification with AllExpectations {

    "My Repository" should {
        "do x" in {
            1 === 1
        }
        "do y" in {
            1 === 1
        }
        "do z" in {
            1 === 1
        }
    }
}
```

- ScalaIDE: 3.0.1-vfinal-20130718-1727-Typesafe
- Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2
- Specs2: "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % 2.2.2

Comment: Which versions of specs2/Eclipse/ScalaIDE are you using?

Comment: added versions to the question

Comment: I can see that Scalatra is referencing a pretty old version of specs2: 1.14. Would you mind trying a more recent one like 2.3.11?

Comment: I took the latest `"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.12",` and it solved the issue. Thank you, Eric. Do you mind moving your suggestion to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the latest specs2 version: `"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.12"`